# Groovy: dynamically create XML for collection of objects with collections of properties

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a collection of fields with properties. Each property is a single value or a collection of objects (either null, one or many)

I need to create a tree like xml for that.

All examples I found so far either static or transform a map to xml.
What is a proper way to add nodes to xml in a cycle?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to convert, and the output XML format you would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing, but without any examples of your input, and desired output it's all just blind guesswork:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def collection = [
  [ name:'tim', pets:['cat','dog'], age:null ],
  [ name:'brenda', pets:null, age:32 ]
]

def process = { binding, element, name ->
  if( element[ name ] instanceof Collection ) {
    element[ name ].each { n ->
      binding."$name"( n )
    }
  }
  else if( element[ name ] ) {
    binding."$name"( element[ name ] )
  }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().with { builder ->
  builder.bind { binding ->
    data {
      collection.each { e ->
        item {
          process( binding, e, 'name' )
          process( binding, e, 'pets' )
          process( binding, e, 'age' )
        }
      }
    }
  }
} )
```

That prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data>
  <item>
    <name>tim</name>
    <pets>cat</pets>
    <pets>dog</pets>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>brenda</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </item>
</data>
```

---

#### edit

Still not sure what you have or want after your comment below, but this seems to fullfil your criteria:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def process = { binding, element, name ->
  if( element[ name ] instanceof Collection ) {
    element[ name ].each { n ->
      binding."$name"( n )
    }
  }
  else if( element[ name ] ) {
    binding."$name"( element[ name ] )
  }
}

class Form {
  List fields  
}

// Create a new Form object
f = new Form( fields:[ [ name:'a', val:21 ], [ name:'b' ], [ name:'c', val:[ 1, 2 ], x:'field x' ] ] )

// Serialize it to XML
println XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().with { builder ->
  builder.bind { binding ->
    data {
      f.fields.each { fields ->
        item {
          fields.each { name, value ->
            process( binding, fields, name )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} )
```

and prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data>
  <item>
    <name>a</name>
    <val>21</val>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>b</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>c</name>
    <val>1</val>
    <val>2</val>
    <x>field x</x>
  </item>
</data>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I just get more confused though :)

let's assume I have an object form which has collection of fields.

    def fields = form.getFields()
    fields.each {field ->
       //here I want to output name of the field
       field.getValues().each {value ->
          //Here I need to list all values of the field (could be many)
       }
    }

Comment: I can't get it to work though

javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script19$_run_closure2_closure4_closure5_closure6_closure7_closure8.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomFieldImpl) values: [Actual result]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll(), findAll(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)
A stacktrace has been logged.

Comment: This sort of thing should go in the question...  You didn't mention anything about Jira, anything about the classes you are using, anything about the version of Groovy you are using, you just asked how to go from a java structure to XML.