# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: groovy

I am getting the following error -
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script64$_run_closure5_closure7_closure8_closure9_closure10_closure11.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:  Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object) error at line:

```
Code -  EDIT
import groovy.xml.*


List tempList = []
List listgenerated = []

def count = 0
for (a in 0..totalCount-1)
{ 

    //nameList and valueList lists will have all the contents added as below   commented pseudo code 
    /*for (b in 0..50) 
    { 
        nameList.add(b,number)     // number is some calculated value
        valueList.add(b,number)
        e.g. nameList=[name1, name2, name3,name4, name5]
             valueList =[val1, val2, val3, , val5]  

             listgenerated should be = [[name1:val1, name2:val2], [name3:val3, name4: , name5:val5]]                          
    } */


        tempList = []

        for (j in count..nameList.size())
        {
                count = j                             
                def nameKey =  nameList[j]
                def value
                if (nameKey != null)
                {
                    value =  valueList[j]
                    tempList << [(nameKey) : value]

                }                               
        }    
            count = count 
            listgenerated.putAt(a,tempList) 
            number = number +1
}   

def process = { binding, element, name ->
  if( element[ name ] instanceof Collection ) {
    element[ name ].each { n ->
      binding."$name"( n )
    }
  }
  else if( element[ name ] ) {
    binding."$name"( element[ name ] )
  }
}

class Form {
  List fields  
}



def list = [[ name:'a', val:'1' ], [ name:'b', val :'2', name2:4, xyz:'abc', pqr:'']]  //Edited list
f = new Form( fields: list )            //Works fine
f = new Form( fields: listgenerated )   //Gives the above error

String xml = XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().with { builder ->
  builder.bind { binding ->
    data {
      f.fields.each { fields ->
        item {
          fields.each { name, value ->
            process( binding, fields, name )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} )
```

If while creating the "listgenerated" single quotes are added around values it takes it as character and while printing both lists seem different.
I am unable to figure it out what exactly is going wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
Ref - [Groovy: dynamically create XML for collection of objects with collections of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279092/groovy-dynamically-create-xml-for-collection-of-objects-with-collections-of-pro)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, where you do:

```
//some loop to add multiple values to the list
listgenerated << name+":"+value
```

You need to do:

```
//some loop to add multiple values to the list
listgenerated << [ (name): value ]
```

And add a map to the list rather than a String.  It's hard to say though as your code example doesn't run without alteration, and I don't know if it's the alterations that are solving the problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tim. But when I am adding a map to the list it is generated as 
listgenerated = [[[name1 : val1],[name2 : val2]], [[name3 : val3]]]  
and I am getting the same error there. If my list is generated as -
listgenerated = [[name1 : val1],[name2 : val2], [name3 : val3]] it works fine but my requirement is  
listgenerated = [[name1 : val1, name2 : val2], [name3 : val3]]. How can i generate the first list by adding map to the list as above.

Comment: @user2239090 can you edit your question so your code actually does what you say it does?  I can't run the above as things are missing

Comment: Hi Tim, I have edited my question to add missing code. Thanks for your help.