# Groovy > Nested Map to Xml

Tags: xml, groovy

I'd like to convert my `Map` object to Xml in Groovy. I've had a look around at the current examples, and I thought this would be much simpler!

All samples I've found, either use [a `MarkupBuilder` to manually specify the fields](http://www.leveluplunch.com/groovy/examples/build-xml-from-map-with-markupbuilder/), or [have a utility method](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/431003) to [iterate over the tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279092/groovy-dynamically-create-xml-for-collection-of-objects-with-collections-of-pro). Most heinous!

Is there something I'm missing? I can convert these other formats simply enough...

```groovy
JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(map))    // json
(map as ConfigObject).writeTo(new StringWriter()) // groovy
new Yaml().dump(map, new StringWriter())          // yml
```

Why can't I just do?

```groovy
XmlUtil.serialize(map)
```

(OR How can I cast my `Map` object to a `Element`/`Node`/`GPathResult`/`Writable` object?)

#### Groovy Sample Code

```groovy
def myMap = [
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: [
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2',
        key3: [
            key1: 'value1',
            key2: 'value2',
        ]
    ]
]
```

#### Preferred output

```xml
<root>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
    <key3>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
        <key3>
            <key1>value1</key1>
            <key2>value2</key2>
        </key3>
    </key3>
</root>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
import groovy.xml.*

new StringWriter().with { sw ->
    new MarkupBuilder(sw).with {
        root { 
            myMap.collect { k, v ->
                "$k" { v instanceof Map ? v.collect(owner) : mkp.yield(v) }
            }
        }
    }
    println sw.toString()
}
```

To output:

```
<root>
  <key1>value1</key1>
  <key2>value2</key2>
  <key3>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
    <key3>
      <key1>value1</key1>
      <key2>value2</key2>
    </key3>
  </key3>
</root>
```

There's no magic method you can call that I'm aware of (probably because due to attributes, there's no magic map -> xml conversion that can be done without knowing the required output structure)

Comment: Note: you need to add `if(v)` in the collect or `v ?: "null"` inside yield to avoid an error when an element has a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution (this also works with List structures)...

**Structure**

```java
def myMap = [
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: [
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2',
        key3: [
            key1: 'value1',
            key2: 'value2',
        ],
        key4: [
            [ k1: true, k2: 123 ],
            [ k1: false, k2: 456 ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Code**

```java
def parseNodes( StringBuilder b, node ){
    if ( node instanceof Map ){
        for ( def e in node ){
            def valuesAsList = e.value instanceof List ? e.value : [ e.value ]
            for ( def nodeElement : valuesAsList ){
                b.append( "<${e.key}>" )
                parseNodes(b, nodeElement)
                b.append( "</${e.key}>" )
            }
        }
    } else if ( node instanceof String ){
        def nodeText = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.escapeXml( node.toString() )
        b.append( nodeText )
    } else if ( node instanceof Number || node instanceof Boolean ){
        b.append( node.toString() )
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Xml parse failed, type " + node.getClass() + " value " + node )
    }
}

def objectToXml( object ){
    def b = new StringBuilder()
    b.append( "<root>" )
    parseNodes(b, object)
    b.append( "</root>" )
    return b.toString()
}

def xml = objectToXml( myMap )
println "Xml result -> " + xml
```

**Result**

```xml
<root>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
    <key3>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
        <key3>
            <key1>value1</key1>
            <key2>value2</key2>
        </key3>
        <key4>
            <k1>true</k1>
            <k2>123</k2>
        </key4>
        <key4>
            <k1>false</k1>
            <k2>456</k2>
        </key4>
    </key3>
</root>
```

... but, I would like to suggest use of an library like Jackson, this libs are better than creating XMLs manually.